# Calling connect/token for authorization_code with PKCE

Tags: identityserver4

Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/YoSKSL

I'm trying to call `connect/token` to exchange a code for a token and I can't use `IdentityModel` because I'm targeting `net40` therefore I need to use `HttpClient` to call the identity endpoints myself.

I've switched to `net6.0` so that I can set a breakpoint on the server to compare my HTTP request to that produced by `IdentityModel`. This led me to add the `Authorization Basic` header.
Strangely, `IdentityModel` omits the `client_id` parameter from the `POST` variables but if I do this then I get a different error.

```
        private void GetToken(string code)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"client_id", "my_client"},
                {"grant_type", "authorization_code"},
                {"code ", code},
                {"code_verifier", _code_verifier},
                {"redirect_uri", "http://localhost:7920/callback"}
            };
            FormUrlEncodedContent urlEncodedParameters = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);


            using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                // https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel/blob/2e94543bb365995fa3fc9201c407acb2b9578d61/src/Client/BasicAuthenticationOAuthHeaderValue.cs#L13
                string credential = $"{UrlEncode("my_client")}:{UrlEncode(string.Empty)}";
                string foo = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(credential));

                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + foo); // dHJ1dGhfbGl0ZV9hZHZpc2VyOg==
                HttpResponseMessage msg = httpClient.PostAsync("https://localhost:5000/connect/token", urlEncodedParameters).Result;
                // This fails.

                // But this works.
                AuthorizationCodeTokenRequest trq = new AuthorizationCodeTokenRequest()
                {
                    Address = "https://localhost:5000/connect/token",
                    ClientId = "truth_lite_adviser",
                    GrantType = "authorization_code",
                    Code = code,
                    CodeVerifier = _code_verifier,
                    RedirectUri = "http://localhost:7920/callback"
                };
                var tkr = httpClient.RequestAuthorizationCodeTokenAsync(trq).Result;
            }
        }
```

In the logs:

```
[Information] @ 05 Oct 10:54:26: POST localhost:5000/connect/token
ConnectionId    : 0HML6LTIMSCR4
ParentId        : 0000000000000000
RequestId       : 0HML6LTIMSCR4:00000002
RequestPath     : /connect/token
SpanId          : a915188809c34ec3
TraceId         : 85a08eed508c195c6d5f9532ad03fc06

[Information] @ 05 Oct 10:54:26: Client Authentication Success
ConnectionId    : 0HML6LTIMSCR4
Event           : Client Authentication Success
ParentId        : 0000000000000000
RequestId       : 0HML6LTIMSCR4:00000002
RequestPath     : /connect/token
SpanId          : a915188809c34ec3
TraceId         : 85a08eed508c195c6d5f9532ad03fc06

[Error] @ 05 Oct 10:54:26: Authorization code is missing, {
  "ClientId": "my_client",
  "ClientName": "TruthLite",
  "GrantType": "authorization_code",
  "AuthorizationCode": "********",
  "RefreshToken": "********",
  "Raw": {
    "client_id": "my_client",
    "grant_type": "authorization_code",
    "code ": "8265CBAE60B416154AF9496051BBF7C86B6309983FAA0A576A79259B2F1E0933-1",
    "code_verifier": "5Rt5NjmvMCJSc-8otBUBlhdTYNp5ba-n15bBVb3iNf6Pzugd11dL_mlqZ8eCGm0b2kO-EUsK1SI7pW7BDizLmw",
    "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:7920/callback"
  }
}
@details        : {
  "ClientId": "my_client",
  "ClientName": "TruthLite",
  "GrantType": "authorization_code",
  "AuthorizationCode": "********",
  "RefreshToken": "********",
  "Raw": {
    "client_id": "my_client",
    "grant_type": "authorization_code",
    "code ": "8265CBAE60B416154AF9496051BBF7C86B6309983FAA0A576A79259B2F1E0933-1",
    "code_verifier": "5Rt5NjmvMCJSc-8otBUBlhdTYNp5ba-n15bBVb3iNf6Pzugd11dL_mlqZ8eCGm0b2kO-EUsK1SI7pW7BDizLmw",
    "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:7920/callback"
  }
}
ConnectionId    : 0HML6LTIMSCR4
ParentId        : 0000000000000000
RequestId       : 0HML6LTIMSCR4:00000002
RequestPath     : /connect/token
SpanId          : a915188809c34ec3
TraceId         : 85a08eed508c195c6d5f9532ad03fc06

[Error] @ 05 Oct 10:54:26: Token Issued Failure
ConnectionId    : 0HML6LTIMSCR4
Event           : Token Issued Failure
ParentId        : 0000000000000000
RequestId       : 0HML6LTIMSCR4:00000002
RequestPath     : /connect/token
SpanId          : a915188809c34ec3
TraceId         : 85a08eed508c195c6d5f9532ad03fc06

[Warning] @ 05 Oct 10:54:26: StatusCode: 400
ConnectionId       : 0HML6LTIMSCR4
ElapsedMilliseconds: 0
Host               : localhost:5000
Method             : POST
ParentId           : 0000000000000000
Path               : /connect/token
RequestId          : 0HML6LTIMSCR4:00000002
RequestPath        : /connect/token
SpanId             : a915188809c34ec3
StatusCode         : 400
TraceId            : 85a08eed508c195c6d5f9532ad03fc06
```

but

> Authorization code is missing
> is obviously bollocks.

What's going on?!

**Update**

Just noticed that the log message thinks that I *have* sent a `refresh_token` and *not* a `code_verifier`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some rough sample code I use in my training classes to authenticate against IdentityServer (using the code flow and PKCE)

Hope you can make some sense out of it and you need to adapt it to your needs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Flurl;
using Flurl.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using OpenID_Connect_client.Models;


//Sample manual authorization code with PKCE
//using the Flurl.Http NuGet package to make HTTP requests
//More details at https://tn-data.se/courses/
public class CodeFlowController : Controller
{
    private readonly IOpenIDSettings _openIdSettings;

    private static string code_verifier;

    public CodeFlowController(IOpenIDSettings openIdSettings)
    {
        this._openIdSettings = openIdSettings;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Start page for the login using the fragment as return type
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IActionResult Login()
    {
        string url = BuildLoginUrl();
        ViewData["loginurl"] = url;

        return View();
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Construct the login URL
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private string BuildLoginUrl()
    {
        //In real life, nonce and state should be random values, but we hardcoded them here for simplicity
        string nonceValue = "1122334455";
        string stateValue = "9988776655";

        //Please redirect us back to this page after successful login
        string redirectUrl = "https://localhost:5001/CodeFlow/callback";

        var url = new Url(_openIdSettings.authorization_endpoint);

        code_verifier = CalculateCryptographicRandomString(43);

        url = url.SetQueryParams(new
        {
            response_type = "code",       //Get both access-token + ID-token
            client_id = "authcodeflowclient",       //Id of this client

            scope = "openid email profile shop.admin",   //openid (required; to indicate that the application intends to use OIDC to verify the user's identity)

            prompt = "consent",                     // Force users to provide consent
            response_mode = "form_post",            // Send the token response as a form post instead of a fragment encoded redirect

            code_challenge = CalculateSha256(code_verifier),    //Add the PKCE headers
            code_challenge_method = "S256",

            state = stateValue,                     // To prevent CSRF attacks
            nonce = nonceValue,                     // To further strengthen the security

            redirect_uri = redirectUrl              // The URL to which the Auth0 will redirect the user's browser after authorization has been granted by the user. 
        });

        return url.ToString();
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// This method is called with the authorization code and state parameter
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="code">authorization code generated by the authorization server. This code is relatively short-lived, typically lasting between 1 to 10 minutes depending on the OAuth service.</param>
    /// <param name="state"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Callback(string code, string state)
    {

        //To be secure then the state parameter should be compared to the state sent in the previous step

        var url = new Url(_openIdSettings.token_endpoint);

        var token = url.PostUrlEncodedAsync(new
        {
            client_id = "authcodeflowclient",       //Id of this client
            client_secret = "mysecret",
            grant_type = "authorization_code",
            code_verifier = code_verifier,
            code = code,
            redirect_uri = "https://localhost:5001/CodeFlow/callback"

        }).ReceiveJson<Token>().Result;

        return View(token);
    }


    public string CalculateSha256(string input)
    {
        using (var sha = SHA256.Create())
        {
            var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
            var hash = sha.ComputeHash(bytes);

            return base64urlencode(hash);
        }
    }

    private string base64urlencode(byte[] arg)
    {
        string s = Convert.ToBase64String(arg); // Regular base64 encoder
        s = s.Split('=')[0]; // Remove any trailing '='s
        s = s.Replace('+', '-'); // 62nd char of encoding
        s = s.Replace('/', '_'); // 63rd char of encoding
        return s;
    }


    private string CalculateCryptographicRandomString(int maxSize)
    {
        char[] chars = new char[62];
        chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890".ToCharArray();

        RNGCryptoServiceProvider crypto = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        var data = new byte[maxSize];
        crypto.GetNonZeroBytes(data);

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(maxSize);
        foreach (byte b in data)
        {
            result.Append(chars[b % (chars.Length - 1)]);
        }
        return result.ToString();
    }
}

   public class Token
    {
        public string access_token { get; set; }
        public string id_token { get; set; }
        public string expires_in { get; set; }
        public string token_type { get; set; }
        public string refresh_token { get; set; }
        public string scope { get; set; }    
    }
```

Comment: So what's the difference?  You're sending a client secret to the token endpoint which shouldn't be necessary for code+PKCE (that's the point of it).

Still don't get why IS is complaining about _code is missing_ -- although it's error messages are usually pretty useless.

Comment: PKCE I think is more to secure that the application making the initial request is also the same as the one doing the request for the tokens using the code. PKCE is similar to the state security check, but a server side check while state is checked client site.

Comment: That's about the size of it. PKCE solves the problem that a client-side application cannot protect a `client_secret`.

Answer (score -1):

```
"code "
```

Two and a half days to find a space.